# File-Specific Bookmarks

Tags: pdf, preview, bookmarks

Is there a feature in Preview that will let me maintain a collection of file-specific bookmarks? For example, I often place bookmarks at the beginning of various chapters in books. I might decide to label a bookmark as "Chapter 1: Introduction".

Unfortunately, the "Bookmarks" menu displays all of the bookmarks that I ever made. This has various problems:

- I can't give two bookmarks the same label.
- The menu becomes cluttered as I accumulate more bookmarks.

Comment: You labeled it pdf, for that I would use adobe reader.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I prefer Preview to Adobe's Reader program.

Comment: Good luck then since Preview is just what it says--a Preview, not a bookmarking tool with options you want.